OpenLayers v10.2.1 Draw and Modify Geodesic Circles
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-geodesic.html
Here as the example are those circles [enter image description here] (https://i.sstatic.net/6HPGpZMB.png)
and in the example of the website allows to drag from the border to modify the size of the circle
I have been a few days to replicate this feature but i am not able to do it
here you can check the website example :
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import {Circle as CircleStyle, Fill, Stroke, Style} from 'ol/style.js';
import {Draw, Modify, Snap} from 'ol/interaction.js';
import {GeometryCollection, Point, Polygon} from 'ol/geom.js';
import {OSM, Vector as VectorSource} from 'ol/source.js';
import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer.js';
import {circular} from 'ol/geom/Polygon.js';
import {getDistance} from 'ol/sphere.js';
import {transform} from 'ol/proj.js';

const raster = new TileLayer({
  source: new OSM(),
});

const source = new VectorSource();

const style = new Style({
  fill: new Fill({
    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
  }),
  stroke: new Stroke({
    color: '#33cc33',
    width: 2,
  }),
  image: new CircleStyle({
    radius: 7,
    fill: new Fill({
      color: '#ffcc33',
    }),
  }),
});

const geodesicStyle = new Style({
  geometry: function (feature) {
    return feature.get('modifyGeometry') || feature.getGeometry();
  },
  fill: new Fill({
    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
  }),
  stroke: new Stroke({
    color: '#ff3333',
    width: 2,
  }),
  image: new CircleStyle({
    radius: 7,
    fill: new Fill({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
    }),
  }),
});

const vector = new VectorLayer({
  source: source,
  style: function (feature) {
    const geometry = feature.getGeometry();
    return geometry.getType() === 'GeometryCollection' ? geodesicStyle : style;
  },
});

const map = new Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [-11000000, 6600000],
    zoom: 3,
  }),
});

const defaultStyle = new Modify({source: source})
  .getOverlay()
  .getStyleFunction();

const modify = new Modify({
  source: source,
  style: function (feature) {
    feature.get('features').forEach(function (modifyFeature) {
      const modifyGeometry = modifyFeature.get('modifyGeometry');
      if (modifyGeometry) {
        const modifyPoint = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
        const geometries = modifyFeature.getGeometry().getGeometries();
        const polygon = geometries[0].getCoordinates()[0];
        const center = geometries[1].getCoordinates();
        const projection = map.getView().getProjection();
        let first, last, radius;
        if (modifyPoint[0] === center[0] && modifyPoint[1] === center[1]) {
          // center is being modified
          // get unchanged radius from diameter between polygon vertices
          first = transform(polygon[0], projection, 'EPSG:4326');
          last = transform(
            polygon[(polygon.length - 1) / 2],
            projection,
            'EPSG:4326',
          );
          radius = getDistance(first, last) / 2;
        } else {
          // radius is being modified
          first = transform(center, projection, 'EPSG:4326');
          last = transform(modifyPoint, projection, 'EPSG:4326');
          radius = getDistance(first, last);
        }
        // update the polygon using new center or radius
        const circle = circular(
          transform(center, projection, 'EPSG:4326'),
          radius,
          128,
        );
        circle.transform('EPSG:4326', projection);
        geometries[0].setCoordinates(circle.getCoordinates());
        // save changes to be applied at the end of the interaction
        modifyGeometry.setGeometries(geometries);
      }
    });
    return defaultStyle(feature);
  },
});

modify.on('modifystart', function (event) {
  event.features.forEach(function (feature) {
    const geometry = feature.getGeometry();
    if (geometry.getType() === 'GeometryCollection') {
      feature.set('modifyGeometry', geometry.clone(), true);
    }
  });
});

modify.on('modifyend', function (event) {
  event.features.forEach(function (feature) {
    const modifyGeometry = feature.get('modifyGeometry');
    if (modifyGeometry) {
      feature.setGeometry(modifyGeometry);
      feature.unset('modifyGeometry', true);
    }
  });
});

map.addInteraction(modify);

let draw, snap; // global so we can remove them later
const typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');

function addInteractions() {
  let value = typeSelect.value;
  let geometryFunction;
  if (value === 'Geodesic') {
    value = 'Circle';
    geometryFunction = function (coordinates, geometry, projection) {
      if (!geometry) {
        geometry = new GeometryCollection([
          new Polygon([]),
          new Point(coordinates[0]),
        ]);
      }
      const geometries = geometry.getGeometries();
      const center = transform(coordinates[0], projection, 'EPSG:4326');
      const last = transform(coordinates[1], projection, 'EPSG:4326');
      const radius = getDistance(center, last);
      const circle = circular(center, radius, 128);
      circle.transform('EPSG:4326', projection);
      geometries[0].setCoordinates(circle.getCoordinates());
      geometry.setGeometries(geometries);
      return geometry;
    };
  }
  draw = new Draw({
    source: source,
    type: value,
    geometryFunction: geometryFunction,
  });
  map.addInteraction(draw);
  snap = new Snap({source: source});
  map.addInteraction(snap);
}

/**
 * Handle change event.
 */
typeSelect.onchange = function () {
  map.removeInteraction(draw);
  map.removeInteraction(snap);
  addInteractions();
};

addInteractions();

But i been trying to replicate it and i keep getting this :
enter image description here
I have been stuck to make it work in my component , for a few days already
This is the code i am working with
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (!this.map) {  
      this.initializeMap();
      this.addInteractions();
      this.updateCircles(this.latitude, this.longitude, this.radius);
    }
  }

  initializeMap(): void {
    const raster = new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM(),
    });

    this.vector = new VectorLayer({
      source: this.source,
      style: () => this.geodesicStyle(),
    });

    this.map = new Map({
      layers: [raster, this.vector],
      target: this.mapContainer.nativeElement,
      view: new View({
        center: fromLonLat([10.0, 50.0]), // Central Europe
        zoom: 4, // Adjust the zoom level
      }),
    });

    const translate = new Translate({
      layers: [this.vector]
    });

    const modify = new Modify({
      source: this.source,
      style: this.geodesicStyle()
    });

    modify.on('modifyend', (event) => {
      const features = this.source.getFeatures();
      if (features.length > 0) {
        const geometry = features[0].getGeometry() as GeometryCollection;
        if (!geometry) return;

        const geometries = geometry.getGeometries();
        const center = (geometries[1] as Point).getCoordinates();
        const edge = (geometries[0] as Polygon).getCoordinates()[0][0];
        const projection = this.map.getView().getProjection();

        const centerCoords = transform(center, projection, 'EPSG:4326');
        const edgeCoords = transform(edge, projection, 'EPSG:4326');
        
        this.longitude = centerCoords[0];
        this.latitude = centerCoords[1];
        this.radius = getDistance(centerCoords, edgeCoords);

        const newCircle = circular([this.longitude, this.latitude], this.radius, 128);
        newCircle.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
        
        geometries[0] = newCircle;
        geometry.setGeometries(geometries);
        
        this.emitCoordinatesChange();
      }
    });

    translate.on('translateend', (event) => {
      const features = this.source.getFeatures();
      if (features.length > 0) {
        const geometry = features[0].getGeometry() as GeometryCollection;
        if (!geometry) return;

        const geometries = geometry.getGeometries();
        const center = (geometries[1] as Point).getCoordinates();
        const edge = (geometries[0] as Polygon).getCoordinates()[0][0];
        const projection = this.map.getView().getProjection();

        const centerCoords = transform(center, projection, 'EPSG:4326');
        const edgeCoords = transform(edge, projection, 'EPSG:4326');
        
        this.longitude = centerCoords[0];
        this.latitude = centerCoords[1];
        this.radius = getDistance(centerCoords, edgeCoords);
        
        this.emitCoordinatesChange();
      }
    });

    this.source.on('change', (event) => {
      const features = this.source.getFeatures();
      if (features.length > 0) {
        const geometry = features[0].getGeometry() as GeometryCollection;
        if (!geometry) return;

        const geometries = geometry.getGeometries();
        const center = (geometries[1] as Point).getCoordinates();
        const edge = (geometries[0] as Polygon).getCoordinates()[0][0];
        const projection = this.map.getView().getProjection();

        const centerCoords = transform(center, projection, 'EPSG:4326');
        const edgeCoords = transform(edge, projection, 'EPSG:4326');
        
        this.longitude = centerCoords[0];
        this.latitude = centerCoords[1];
        this.radius = getDistance(centerCoords, edgeCoords);
        
        this.emitCoordinatesChange();
      }
    });

    this.map.addInteraction(modify);
    this.map.addInteraction(translate);
  }

  calculateRadius(polygon: Polygon): number {
    const coordinates = polygon.getCoordinates()[0];
    const first = coordinates[0];
    const last = coordinates[Math.floor(coordinates.length / 2)];

    const center = transform(first, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
    const edge = transform(last, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');

    return getDistance(center, edge);
  }

  addInteractions(): void {
    let geometryFunction = (coordinates: any, geometry: any) => {
      if (!geometry) {
        geometry = new GeometryCollection([new Polygon([]), new Point(coordinates[0])]);
      }
      const geometries = geometry.getGeometries();
      const center = transform(coordinates[0], 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
      const last = transform(coordinates[1], 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
      const radius = getDistance(center, last);
    
      const circle = circular(center, radius, 128);
      circle.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
      geometries[0].setCoordinates(circle.getCoordinates());
      geometries[1].setCoordinates(coordinates[0]);  
      geometry.setGeometries(geometries);
      return geometry;
    };
    

    this.draw = new Draw({
      source: this.source,
      type: 'Circle',
      geometryFunction: geometryFunction,
    });

    this.draw.on('drawstart', () => {
      this.source.clear();  
    });

    this.modify = new Modify({
      source: this.source,
      style: this.geodesicStyle(),
      insertVertexCondition: () => true 
    });

    this.modify.on('modifyend', (event) => {
      const features = this.source.getFeatures();
      if (features.length > 0) {
        const geometry = features[0].getGeometry() as GeometryCollection;
        if (!geometry) return;

        const geometries = geometry.getGeometries();
        const center = (geometries[1] as Point).getCoordinates();
        const edge = (geometries[0] as Polygon).getCoordinates()[0][0];
        const projection = this.map.getView().getProjection();

        const centerCoords = transform(center, projection, 'EPSG:4326');
        const edgeCoords = transform(edge, projection, 'EPSG:4326');
        
        this.longitude = centerCoords[0];
        this.latitude = centerCoords[1];
        this.radius = getDistance(centerCoords, edgeCoords);

        const newCircle = circular([this.longitude, this.latitude], this.radius, 128);
        newCircle.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
        
        geometries[0] = newCircle;
        geometry.setGeometries(geometries);
        
        this.emitCoordinatesChange();
      }
    });

    this.map.addInteraction(this.draw);
    this.map.addInteraction(this.modify);
    this.snap = new Snap({ source: this.source });
    this.map.addInteraction(this.snap);
  }

  emitCoordinates(feature: any): void {
    const geometry = feature.getGeometry() as GeometryCollection;
    const geometries = geometry.getGeometries();
    const center = transform((geometries[1] as Point).getCoordinates(), 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
    const edge = transform((geometries[0] as Polygon).getCoordinates()[0][0], 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
    const radius = getDistance(center, edge);

    this.coordinatesChange.emit({
      latitude: center[1],
      longitude: center[0],
      radius: radius,
    });
  }

  geodesicStyle() {
    return new Style({
      fill: new Fill({
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
      }),
      stroke: new Stroke({
        color: '#ff3333',
        width: 2,
      }),
      image: new CircleStyle({
        radius: 7,
        fill: new Fill({
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
        }),
      }),
    });
  }

  modifyStyle(feature: any) {
    return this.geodesicStyle();
  }

  onTypeChange(event: any): void {
    const selectedType = event.target.value;

    this.map.removeInteraction(this.draw);
    this.map.removeInteraction(this.snap);

    let geometryFunction = (coordinates: any, geometry: any) => {
      if (!geometry) {
        geometry = new GeometryCollection([new Polygon([]), new Point(coordinates[0])]);
      }
      const geometries = geometry.getGeometries();
      const center = transform(coordinates[0], 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
      const last = transform(coordinates[1], 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
      const radius = getDistance(center, last);
    
      const circle = circular(center, radius, 128);
      circle.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
      geometries[0].setCoordinates(circle.getCoordinates());
      geometries[1].setCoordinates(coordinates[0]);  // Correctly set center as a point
      geometry.setGeometries(geometries);
      return geometry;
    };

    this.draw = new Draw({
      source: this.source,
      type: 'Circle',
      geometryFunction: geometryFunction,
    });

    this.map.addInteraction(this.draw);
    this.snap = new Snap({ source: this.source });
    this.map.addInteraction(this.snap);
  }

  addMapClickListener(): void {
    this.map.on('click', (event) => {
      const clickedCoord = this.map.getCoordinateFromPixel(event.pixel);
      const lonLat = transform(clickedCoord, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');

      this.longitude = lonLat[0];
      this.latitude = lonLat[1];
      this.radius = this.radius || 1000;

      this.updateCircles(this.latitude, this.longitude, this.radius);
    });
  }

  updateCircles(latitude: number, longitude: number, radius: number): void {
    this.source.clear(); 
    
    const validRadius = radius || 100000;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.radius = validRadius;
  
    const circle = circular([this.longitude, this.latitude], validRadius, 128);
    circle.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
    
    const center = fromLonLat([this.longitude, this.latitude]);
    const point = new Point(center);
    
    const geometryCollection = new GeometryCollection([
      circle,
      point
    ]);
    
    const feature = new Feature({
      geometry: geometryCollection
    });
    
    this.source.addFeature(feature);
   
    const zoomLevel = Math.max(1, Math.min(16, Math.floor(16 - Math.log(radius / 1000) / Math.LN2)));
    this.map.getView().setCenter(center);
    this.map.getView().setZoom(zoomLevel);
  }
  
  

  private emitCoordinatesChange(): void {
    this.coordinatesChange.emit({
      latitude: this.latitude,
      longitude: this.longitude,
      radius: this.radius
    });
  }

}```



I assume the error or the duplication it may be between the draw feature or with the updates but i dont know what to check anymore :)


In the first example the Modify style function calculates and displays an updated circle, and saves it as the modifyGeometry property.  Without that you are simply modifying a polygon.

thanks for the head up , i tryied your advice but it keeps the same

@Mike you were right the problem was not exactly in the modify style but in the geodesic style and what you said about the modifygeometry , thanks  a lot
